# making python code faster using numba, cache or any other optimization

Tags: python, list, performance, numba

I have defined the following function

```
def laplacian_2D_array(func_2D):
    func_2nd_derv_x_fin2D = np.zeros((N,N))
    for j in range (0,N):
        func_CD2_x_list = []
        for i in range (0,N):
            value = func_2D[i][j] #func_2D is a NxN matrix
            func_CD2_x_list.append(value)
        func_CD2_x_array = np.array (func_CD2_x_list)[np.newaxis]
        func_2nd_derv_x = matrix_R @ (np.transpose(func_CD2_x_array))
        func_2nd_derv_x_fin2D[j] = np.transpose (np.reshape(func_2nd_derv_x,[N,]))

    func_2nd_derv_y_fin2D = np.zeros((N,N))
    for i in range (0,N):
        func_CD2_y_list = []
        for j in range (0,N):
            value = func_2D[i][j]
            func_CD2_y_list.append(value)
        func_CD2_y_array = np.array (func_CD2_y_list)[np.newaxis]
        func_2nd_derv_y = matrix_S @ (np.transpose(func_CD2_y_array))
        func_2nd_derv_y_fin2D[i] = (np.reshape(func_2nd_derv_y,[N,]))    
    return (np.add(func_2nd_derv_x_fin2D, func_2nd_derv_y_fin2D))
```

In the above code a 2D matrix `func_2D`each j row is extracted as column vector and multiplied with matrix_R and stored in jth column of `func_2nd_derv_x_fin2D` and similarly of 2nd block of code and finally function returns the addition of `func_2nd_derv_x_fin2D` and `func_2nd_derv_y_fin2D`

In this `N = 401` and `matrix_S` and `matrix_R`are also N X N matrices. This function is being called multiple times in a while loop and execution of single iteration is taking a lot of time. I have tried `@njit` to make it faster but I am not successful in doing so and getting errors. I have also tried using `cache`.

How can we optimise for lists and arrays in this and what are other ways to optimize the defined function?

I am showing the code where the function is used.

```
while (time<timemax):

    #Analytical Solution----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    exact_time = time/a_sec
    omega_t = np.zeros((N,N))
    psi_t = np.zeros((N,N))
    for i in range (0,N):
        for j in range (0,N):
            psi_t[i][j] = np.sin(x_list[i]) * np.sin(y_list[j]) * np.exp((-2*exact_time)/Re)
            omega_t[i][j] = 2*np.sin (x_list[i]) * np.sin(y_list[j]) * np.exp((-2*exact_time)/Re)
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
    # BiCGSTAB algo

    x0 = psi_0 #initial guess--> psi of previous time step
    r0 = omega_0 - laplacian_2D_array(x0) # r0 = b-Ax0
    r0_hat = r0
    rho_0 = 1
    alpha = 1
    w0 = 1
    v0 = np.zeros((N,N))
    P_0 = np.zeros((N,N))
    tol = 10 ** (-7)
    iteration = 0
    while ((np.max(np.abs(laplacian_2D_array(x0) - omega_0))) < tol):
        rho_prev = rho_0
        rho = np.dot ((np.reshape(r0_hat,(N**2,1))),(np.reshape(r0,(N**2,1))))
        beta = (rho/rho_prev) * (alpha/w0)
        P_0 = r0 + beta * (P_0 - w0 * v0)
        v0 = laplacian_2D_array(P_0)
        alpha = rho / np.dot ((np.reshape(r0_hat,(N**2,1))),(np.reshape(v0,(N**2,1)))) 
        s = r0 - alpha * v0
        t = laplacian_2D_array(s)
```

Any suggestions to fasten code is highly appreciable.

Comment: If this code works and you're looking for optimizations, [codereview.se] might be a more suitable place to ask

Comment: For one, when you're working with Numpy and you find yourself using a regular `for` loop, chances are you're doing things in a suboptimal way.

Comment: `func_CD2_x_list = func_2D[:,j]` replaces your inner loop.

Comment: Please provide an example of usage of the function or describe *precisely* all the types (since in Numba types are critical and this might explain why you got errors). Reproducible example help us to check results, compare performance and get typing informations.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I have edited the question and added the usage as well. Could you suggest some ways to fasten it?

Comment: What you are doing is matrix multiplication of two matrices and adding them...This what I analysed after seeing @JérômeRichard answer. Maybe once you could check your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the complicated code of `laplacian_2D_array` can be simplified as the following implementation:

```py
def laplacian_2D_array(func_2D):
    return (matrix_R @ func_2D + matrix_S @ func_2D.T).T
```

This is 63 times faster on my machine on random matrices based on your provided inputs. Most of the time should be spent in the matrix multiplication (performed very efficiently in parallel if the installation of Numpy/Python/BLAS is done correctly on the target platform).

Comment: I think the user doesn't want to directly multiply the two matrices as suggested in the answer. I feel that in this we have to multiply `matrix_R` with every column of `func_2D` separately and store that resultant column vector in some matrix in the same column as that used while extracting columns from `func_2D`. Is the code suggested by you doing the same? @JérômeRichard

Comment: @Avii The code gives the exact same results. But I am suspicious about the validity of the original code regarding the needs of the OP. I assumed the original code is correct since I have no way to ensure this.